# Calculating a Hilbert Function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05646?context=math.AG), and in page $3$ is calculated the Hilbert Function for an surface $S$ with degree $d\ge 4$ in $\mathbb P^3$. I' ve tried to use the method described [here](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~dmehrle/notes/old/alggeo/40HilbertFunctionIntro.pdf), but I can't get the same result. Any clue in how to compute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty rusty, sorry if I'm missing something.  In particular I don't see how degree $\ge 4$ matters.

The ring of regular functions is given by $R/(f)$ where $R=\mathbb{k}[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$ and $f$ has homogeneous degree $d$.   Looking at the degree $x$ part of this quotient, it's the quotient 
$$
R_{x}/(R_{x-d}f)
$$

and $\dim(R_x) = \binom{x+3}{3}$ and $\dim(R_{x-d})=\binom{x-d+3}{3}$